# Unable to install DevKit Plugin

Tags: mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule-sdk

I'm trying to install Devkit plugin in anypoint studio and after following below steps:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/connector-devkit/3.9/setting-up-your-dev-environment im getting below error message, Please help

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: Anypoint DevKit Extension
>   1.1.5.201608221430 (org.mule.tooling.devkit.extension.feature.group 1.1.5.201608221430)'
>        Missing requirement: org.mule.tooling.devkit 1.1.5.201608221430 (org.mule.tooling.devkit 1.1.5.201608221430) requires 'osgi.bundle;
>   org.mule.tooling.runtime [6.1.0,7.0.0)' but it could not be found
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Anypoint DevKit Extension 1.1.5.201608221430 (org.mule.tooling.devkit.extension.feature.group 1.1.5.201608221430)
>       To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.mule.tooling.devkit [1.1.5.201608221430,1.1.5.201608221430]

Comment: using Version: 7.4.2, Build Id: 202001311805 trial version

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to install DevKit in Studio 7.x. DevKit is designed to work with Mule 3.x and its matching Studio version, which is Studio 6.x. It is not compatible with Studio 7. Try with the last version of Studio 6 available at this time, currently 6.6.11 as of September 2023. Check on the [Studio 6 release notes](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/studio/anypoint-studio) to see which is the latest. Download page: https://www.mulesoft.com/lp/dl/studio/previous.

If instead you are trying to develop connectors and modules for Mule 4.x, then you have to use the [Mule SDK](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/). Currently there is no Studio plugin for Mule SDK. It is based on Maven. You should use Maven on the command line or a different IDE to create a project, [as mentioned in the documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/getting-started).